# OnLongClickListener Doesn't Start Video Recording CWAC-Camera

Tags: android, camera, cwac-camera

I am trying implementation like SnapChat where the user clicks the button it captures photo and when user holds button video recording starts.

I am using CamerView of CWAC-Camera Library for my camera implementation.

This is in my onCreate Method where I have Assigned the button with **CLickListeners** and **Boolean** for **TakingVideo**

```
 btnTakePhoto.setOnLongClickListener(takeVideoListener);
        btnTakePhoto.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        TakingVideo = false;
```

Here are the Methods for OnlongClickListeners and OnTouchListeners;

```
 private View.OnLongClickListener takeVideoListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            TakingVideo = true;
            try {
                if (cameraView.record()) {
                    Toast.makeText(TakePhotoActivity.this,"Is Recording",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //TODO: show an error to the user
                    try {
                        cameraView.stopRecording();
                        Toast.makeText(TakePhotoActivity.this,"Stopped Recording",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           return true;
        }
    };


    private View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (TakingVideo) {
                    Toast.makeText(TakePhotoActivity.this,"Finished Recording",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    TakingVideo = false;
                    TakenVideo.start();
                    try {
                        cameraView.stopRecording();
                        Toast.makeText(TakePhotoActivity.this,"Stop Recording",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(TakePhotoActivity.this,"Error Stop Recording",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

And the Button has also been assigned to Take Photo OnClick

```
   @OnClick(R.id.btnTakePhoto)
    public void onTakePhotoClick() {
        btnTakePhoto.setEnabled(false);
        cameraView.takePicture(true, true);
        animateShutter();
    }
```

So far the on TouchListener is working fine but onLongClick Listener doesn't work.

Here is the Link for [CWAC-Camera's CameraView Class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraView.java)

Comment: The library you cited has been discontinued. I strongly encourage you to work with the camera APIs directly.

Comment: How to go about accessing Camera API directly with using Camera view.

Comment: @CommonsWare how to go about saving recorded videos or callback for previewing recorded videos?

Comment: And how can I access mediarecorder api directly with the cameraView layout?